# Web page crashes in iOS 7

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, ios7

**UPDATE:** I figured it out. iOS 7 does NOT like vh units. So I switched to using JavaScript for detecting browser height, and it now works on iOS 7.

I've made a website that works on all devices I've tested except iPhones with iOS 7. The whole page crashes, and does this crazy disco flickering thing.

The result on iOS 7 can be seen here: http://morten-hauge.com/diverse/ios7_fail.MOV

If I remove my CSS file the page loads as you would expect for a page without CSS.

```
*
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

a, a img
{
text-decoration: none;
border-style: none;
}

#splash-container
{
position: fixed;
top: 40px;
right: 40px;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

img.splash
{
display: block;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin: 0 0 20px 0;

transition-duration: .2s, .2s; 
transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;

-ms-transition-duration: .2s, .2s; 
-ms-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;

-webkit-transition-duration: .2s, .2s; 
-webkit-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;

-o-transition-duration: .2s, .2s; 
-o-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;

-moz-transition-duration: .2s, .2s; 
-moz-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;
}

img.splash:hover
{
transform: scale(1.1);
-ms-transform: scale(1.1);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
-o-transform: scale(1.1);
-moz-transform: scale(1.1);
cursor: pointer; 
}

#splash1-mobil
{
display: none;
}


.pil
{
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
margin: 160px auto 0 auto;
padding: 0;
position: relative;

animation:          arrowAni 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
-webkit-animation:  arrowAni 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
-moz-animation:     arrowAni 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
-o-animation:       arrowAni 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
-ms-animation:      arrowAni 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;

-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

img.pil
{
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

a img.pil
{
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

@keyframes arrowAni 
{
0%   { bottom: 10px;}
50%  { bottom: 30px;}
100% { bottom: 10px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes arrowAni 
{
0%   { bottom: 10px;}
50%  { bottom: 30px;}
100% { bottom: 10px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes arrowAni 
{
0%   { bottom: 10px;}
50%  { bottom: 30px;}
100% { bottom: 10px;}
}

@-o-keyframes arrowAni 
{
0%   { bottom: 10px;}
50%  { bottom: 30px;}
100% { bottom: 10px;}
}

@-ms-keyframes arrowAni 
{
0%   { bottom: 10px;}
50%  { bottom: 30px;}
100% { bottom: 10px;}
}


.section
{
width: 100%;
height: 80vh;
padding: 30vh 0 50px 0;
text-align: center;
}


.content
{
background: #FFF;
background: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
padding: 40px 40px 20px 40px;
width: 40%;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}

#intro
{
background: url('img/intro.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
}

span.handsome
{
font-family: 'Handsome';
text-transform: none;
font-size: 45px;
line-height: 10px;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

h1,h2
{
font-family: 'GarageGothic';
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 60px;
}

h2
{
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

h3
{
font-family: 'GarageGothic';
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 40px;
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.content p
{
font-family: 'OpenSans';
margin: 0 0 30px 0;
font-size: 18px;
}

.button
{
font-family: 'GarageGothic';
font-size: 30px;
background: #e65a50;
padding: 5px 30px 5px 30px;
cursor: pointer;
margin: 20px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 0px #bfbfbf;
-moz-box-shadow:    5px 5px 0px #bfbfbf;
box-shadow:         5px 5px 0px #bfbfbf;
text-align: center;
color: #000;
}

.button:hover
{
background: #ff665b;
}

.button:active
{
background: #e65a50;
}

.button-clicked
{
background: #d4edb5;
cursor: default;
}

.button-clicked:hover
{
background: #d4edb5;
}

.disabled
{
opacity: .5;
background: #CCC;
cursor: default;
}

.disabled:hover
{
background: #CCC;
}

.button a, .button a:visited
{
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
}

span.steps
{
font-family: 'OpenSans';
font-size: 10px;
margin: 40px 0 0 0;
display: block;
color: #7e7e7e;
}

ul#sticky
{
position: fixed;
top: 25px;
left: 25px;
}

ul#sticky li
{
font-family: 'OpenSans';
padding: 10px;
color: #000;
background: #FFF;   
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
border-left: 1px solid #FFF;
font-size: 12px;
list-style: none;
}

ul#sticky li:first-child
{
border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
background: #FFF;
background: rgba(255,255,255, .8);
font-family: 'GarageGothic';
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 20px;
text-align: center;
}

img.checkmark
{
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
margin: 0 3px 0 0;
}

#vann-section
{
background: url('img/vann.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
}

#ifboligsjekk-section
{
background: url('img/ifboligsjekk.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
}

#boligsjekk-splash
{
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
display: block;
left: 25%;
margin: -50px 0 0 0;
position: absolute;

transition-duration: .2s, .2s; 
transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;

-ms-transition-duration: .2s, .2s; 
-ms-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;

-webkit-transition-duration: .2s, .2s; 
-webkit-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;

-o-transition-duration: .2s, .2s; 
-o-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;

-moz-transition-duration: .2s, .2s; 
-moz-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;

-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#boligsjekk-splash:hover
{
transform: scale(1.1);
-ms-transform: scale(1.1);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
-o-transform: scale(1.1);
-moz-transform: scale(1.1);
cursor: pointer; 
}

#brannskader-section
{
background: url('img/brann.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
}

#handverker-section
{
background: url('img/håndverker.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
}

#sopp-section
{
background: url('img/sopp.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
}

#dyroginsekter-section
{
background: url('img/skadedyr.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
}

#leieinntekt-section
{
background: url('img/leieinntekt.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
}

#rettshjelp-section
{
background: url('img/rettshjelp.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
}

#tyveri-section
{
background: url('img/tyveri.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
}

#naturskade-section
{
background: url('img/naturskade.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
}

#resultat
{
width: 100%;
min-height: 80vh;
height: 100%;
padding: 30vh 0 50px 0;
text-align: center;
background: url('img/res.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
}

#resultat .content
{
padding: 40px;
}

#resultat p
{
line-height: 28px;
}

#resultat .button
{
display: inline-block;
font-size: 20px;
}

#button-ops-container
{
font-family: 'GarageGothic';
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 30px;
background: #e65a50;
padding: 5px 30px 5px 30px;
cursor: pointer;
margin: 20px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 0px #bfbfbf;
-moz-box-shadow:    5px 5px 0px #bfbfbf;
-o-box-shadow:      5px 5px 0px #bfbfbf;
-ms-box-shadow:     5px 5px 0px #bfbfbf;
box-shadow:         5px 5px 0px #bfbfbf;
text-align: center;
color: #000;
}

#button-ops-container:hover
{
background: #ff665b;
}

#button-ops-container:active
{
background: #e65a50;
}

#ops 
{ 
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
}

#ops:visited
{
color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right off the bat, I would try removing any CSS `animation`, `transform` and `perspective` and  and see if that stops the flicker. Hard to tell without knowing excactly what is done with scripting, and how elements are layered.